# Disable a UIButton until 4 UITextField s are filled in

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios

I have 2 UIButtons on my app and I want them both to be disabled until data has been entered into all 4 UITextFields above. my code is as follows but both buttons stay disabled.

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (([brand.text length] >0) && ([qty.text length] >0) && ([size.text length] >0) && ([price.text length] >0)) {
        [calcOneButton setEnabled:YES];
        [calcTwoButton setEnabled:YES];
    }
}
```

Look forward to your replies

Comment: Just to make sure, are all outlets connected?

Comment: Check the userInteractionEnabled flag as well, or override if necessary.

Comment: @Krypton the flags are all enabled

Comment: @Deepak The referencing Outlets are all connected, but do I connect the delegate outlet to the view, first responder or file owner?

Comment: @Deepak I only have the 3 options in my .xib file, the view, first responder and file owner, are view and view controller the same thing?
i notice that a view controller can be added from the library??

Comment: I think the `File Owner`s class should be the view controller's class name. Connect the delegate to it.

Comment: OK I;ve got it, however, if the data in one of the fields is deleted, the buttons are still active, I need to create some sort of loop, any idea's best weay to start? Will it be another IF statement?

Comment: try putting it inside `– textFieldDidEndEditing:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

textFieldDidBeginEditing is a delegate method so you will want to make sure in your .h file you have `<UITextFieldDelegate>` and that you set the delegate of each text field to be the view controller using something like: `brand.delegate=self;` and then also make sure your outlets are connection if you are creating your textfield in interface builder.